# Hibernate Query Restriction: NULL or Trim Whitespace Empty-String

Tags: hibernate

**Added the Child-Table issue**

One of my Hibernate Query restrictions is **either a NULL or a trimmed-empty string**.

The following `OR`-Restriction with a `TRIM(..)` doesn't work because it's not a `SQLRestriction`.

```
final Criteria query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(PeopleT.class); 
query.add(Restrictions.or(
      Restrictions.eq("TRIM(childTable.commentText)",""),
      Restrictions.isNull("childTable.commentText"))
);
```

The error I get is

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: TRIM(
```

But can I have one OR part a SQLRestriction and the other just a plain Restriction? Is that the way to handle this test? Note: I have a child table here.

Comment: Whats your database?

Comment: Oracle 12c......

Comment: This works in MySQL but not all databases have a TRIM() function. Other DB have LTRIM() and RTRIM() so you'd have to call it like LTRIM(RTRIM(...)).

Comment: Yeah but the problem is the Hibernate syntax. with LTRIM/RTRIM I'm still getting could not resolve property: LTRIM(RTRIM(...)

Comment: Had you tried 'sqlRestrictions' instead of 'Restrictions'?

Comment: Sorry I mean instead of eq

Comment: one second.......

Comment: The problem is I have a child table here. I can't say Restrictions.sqlRestriction("TRIM(childTable.commentText) = ''") paired with the OR Restrictions.isNull("childTable.commentText"). Otherwise the SQL doesn't use Hibernate's alias for the child table in the SqlException. And I get a Could Not Extract Resultset error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("{alias}.TRIMcommentText) = ?", ""), StringType.INSTANCE))
```

Comment: I updated my post, the problem is the Child Table. The alias doesn't match, e.g. ChildTable.commentText to Hibernate's childtabl1_.commentText.